# Bash in KDE console shows wrong info

Tags: bash

In Konsole of Slackware 14.2, bash shows bash-4.3$. I tried to change it, but no effect. How to change it permanently as user@hostname$ and for root, root@hostname#?

Answer (score 0):

Your question was already answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35780/154078).

> This is changed by changing the environment variable `PS1`.
>
> You can see the current value of `PS1` by:
>
> ```
> root@monu dev# echo $PS1
> ```
>
> You can see the value to be equal to `\u@\h \w\$`, where:
>
> - `\u` : username
> - `\h` : hostname
> - `\w` : current working directory
> - `\$` : a `#` symbol for the root user, a `$` symbol for other users
>
> If you want the change to be permanent, you have to add the script
>   changing the value of `PS1` in `~/.bashrc`, since that it gets
>   executed every time a user logs in.